# The provided cwd "" does not exist in php artisan

Tags: php, docker

PHP 7.3 running inside a container and under the root user. I've tried to delete 'vendor' directory, it didn't help.

The issued command:

`php artisan -v common:create-phpunit-config` executed in / directory in a Ubuntu (16.04) container.

Result:

Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException  : The provided cwd "" does not exist.

```
at /vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:334
   330|             }
   331|         }
   332| 
   333|         if (!is_dir($this->cwd)) {
 > 334|             throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('The provided cwd "%s" does not exist.', $this->cwd));
   335|         }
   336| 
   337|         $this->process = proc_open($commandline, $descriptors, $this->processPipes->pipes, $this->cwd, $envPairs, $options);
   338|
```

Expected behavior:

`php artisan -v common:create-phpunit-config` executed with no errors.

For what directory php is looking for? What am I missing?

Comment: As you can see cwd is empty. You will have to check how cwd is being read by symfony and might have to adapt your PHP configuration. If it's a Ubuntu container it seems odd to just run it in root.

Comment: How to understand or see what's cwd at the time of command execution?

Comment: You can already see what the value is at the time of execution, it's empty for symfony. You would have to follow the code or write a MWE to actually get a the current working directory without symfony. Might be worth it to check the bugtracker of symfony. Might even be in the documentation looking at [this](https://github.com/symfony/panther/issues/152).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was because I was using the root directory. I don't know why php doesn't like it but it solved the problem.